# JComboBox doesnt change

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am working with a JComboBox for my java program, and the box is coded like this

```
JComboBox category = new JComboBox(cats);
category.addActionListener(this);
category.setActionCommand("combo");
category.setBounds(125,200,400,50);
add(category);
```

where cats is a String array. However, even when I change the selected index, the `getSelectedIndex()` method still returns 0. Please help.

Comment: How do you change the selected index? Your code is incomplete.

Comment: By clicking on it and changing in the Jframe

Comment: Where are you calling `getSelectedIndex()` ?

Comment: it is still incomplete. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am calling `getSelectedIndex()` in the actionPerformed method

Comment: *I am calling `getSelectedIndex()` in the actionPerformed method*, and why you haven't added the code of the `actionPerformed`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
String[] cats = new String[] {"meow1", "meow2"};
JComboBox<String> category = new JComboBox<>(cats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
JComboBox category = new JComboBox();
category.addActionListener(this);
category.setActionCommand("combo");
category.setBounds(125,200,400,50);
add(category);

category.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(cats));
```